# ¿Existe un antónimo de la palabra "lógica" como sustantivo derivado de la misma palabra?

Tags: etimología, solicitud-de-término, sustantivos, antónimos

La palabra *lógica* como adjetivo tiene antónimos, por ejemplo *ilógica*, *irracional*, etc.
El antónimo como adjetivo de *ilógica* deriva de la misma palabra *lógica*. Por ejemplo: "Esa idea es ilógica".

¿Pero qué hay de la palabra *lógica* como sustantivo? O sea de la disciplina que estudia las formas y principios generales que rigen el conocimiento y el pensamiento humano.

¿Tiene esta palabra como sustantivo, "la lógica" un antónimo derivado de la misma palabra, de la misma forma que lo tiene esta palabra cuando se usa como adjetivo?

Uno podría decir que un antónimo de la palabra "Lógica" como sustantivo es "(La) irracionalidad" pero esta palabra no deriva de la palabra primitiva Lógica, y en la pregunta me refiero a una palabra derivada.

Comment: No veo en qué medida puede haber un antónimo sobre el nombre de una disciplina. ¿Cuál sería el antónimo de Matemáticas, Filología o Epistemología?

Comment: En su sentido más amplio, hablaríamos de "falta de lógica".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque no está recogida en el DLE, la palabra *ilogicidad* parece encontrar uso en el Derecho, al menos en algunos países (se habla por ejemplo de "ilogicidad en la motivación de la sentencia"). La RAE dice [en Twitter](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/524196807052910593) que "se trata de un derivado correcto de «ilógico» que se documenta principalmente en textos de especialidad."

[image]

Buscando un poco también se la encuentra en textos filosóficos ("la ilogicidad del mundo") y como un síntoma en descripciones de trastornos psicológicos o psiquiátricos.